# Html div changes width when write text

Tags: javascript, html

How to make a fixed size of an div element?

So that when i write in it ,it won't change the width.
Can't figure out what i did wrong.

part of code with css :

```
var table = document.body.getElementsByTagName("table");

for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
    table[i].style.border = "solid";
    table[i].style.borderWidth = "1px";
    table[i].style.width = "1024px";
    table[i].style.height = "auto";
    table[i].style.textAlign = "left";
};

var tdAll = document.body.getElementsByTagName("td");

for (var i = 0; i < tdAll.length; i++) {
    tdAll[i].style.border = "1px solid #dddddd";
    tdAll[i].style.height = "30px";
};

var divALL = document.body.getElementsByTagName("div");

for (var i = 0; i < divALL.length; i++) {
    divALL[i].style.height = "100%";
    divALL[i].style.width = "100%";
    divALL[i].style.lineHeight = "25px";
};
```

whole code on fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/zzduqpky/

Comment: set `overflow: hidden`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding  `table-layout:fixed` to my table styles. The table cell and div doesn't expand anymore.

Thank you everyone for their time!!!

Answer (score 2):

set `max-width` property

e.g. `max-width="100px"`

this will fixed the problem of div width.